# Iterate through variable containing mysql data (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loops

I am trying to get data from mysql with javascript and then do some things with each of the results. I have saved the mysql result to a variable and thought that I could iterate through this, but I cant understand how to do it.

To make it easy I have simplified the code as below, which uses forEach():

```
connection.query("SELECT length, weight FROM physics WHERE user = 'Test' AND name = 'Hi'", function (err, result) { 
      if (err) throw err;
      allres = result; 

allres.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(`I looped: ${name}`);
  });
    });
```

The result is:

```
I looped: [object Object]
I looped: [object Object]
I looped: [object Object]
```

If I do *console.log(allres)* I get:

```
RowDataPacket { length: '5', weight: '3' },
  RowDataPacket { length: '11', weight: '11' },
  RowDataPacket { length: '2', weight: '2' },
```

So the values are there, but how can I loop this?

Comment: When you do `I looped: ${name}`, `toString()` get's called on `name`, which for objects returns `[object Object]`. Instead, try accessing properties on the object, like `I looped: ${name.length}`, or convert the object to JSON: `I looped: ${JSON.stringify(name)}`

Comment: You are right, using properties did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you combine the `object` with a `string` it will console log everything as a string. You have a few options:

**Console log the object by itself**

```
connection.query("SELECT length, weight FROM physics WHERE user = 'Test' AND name = 'Hi'", function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('I have ' + result.length + ' results');

    result.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log('I looped:'); // string
        console.log(entry); // object
    });
});
```

**Console log each piece of each object**

```
connection.query("SELECT length, weight FROM physics WHERE user = 'Test' AND name = 'Hi'", function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('I have ' + result.length + ' results');

    result.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        console.log('for entry with an index of : ' + index);
        console.log('the length value is : ' + entry.length);
        console.log('the weight value is : ' + entry.weight);
    });
});
```

**Use the `util` module for nice tidy logging of nested objects**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/util

```
var util = require('util')

connection.query("SELECT length, weight FROM physics WHERE user = 'Test' AND name = 'Hi'", function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(util.inspect(result, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i in name) {
    let item = name[i];
    // do something with item
}
```

Or you can access the values directly:

```
let length = name.length;
let weight = data.weight;
```